# jQuery: Gif (css-background) gets reset on animating container (Firefox only)

Tags: jquery, firefox, animated-gif

It seems that I get the strange behaviour of a GIF-Animation starting over again, and this only in Firefox.

**Scenario:**

On a click, a div get's resized in width. This div has set, as a background-property in CSS, a color and a GIF.
At the start and the end of the animation the GIF gets reset, but only in Firefox 8.0

**Demonstration**

I created a jsFiddle under http://jsfiddle.net/ms8yd/ (with a test-image found by Google Images).

Tested this in IE 9, newest Chrome, Firefox 8.0 under Windows 7.

**Question**

Does somebody know as of why this happens and a fix to prevent this?
Or, if there is no fix and that's just strictly the behaviour of FireFox, can anyone provide me a Work-Around?

Thanks,
Shion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be reset if the DIV is resized.

Live DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ms8yd/1/

Script:

```
$('p').click(function() {
    var $div = $('div');
    var width = $div.width() == 350 ? 100 : 350;
    $('#loader').animate({
        'width': width
    }, 500);
});
```

HTML

```
<p>Click me for the Effect</p><br />
<br />
<div id="loader"><img src="http://www.askmaps.in/Content/images/loading.gif" /></div>
```

CSS

```
p
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

div#loader
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: #000000;
}
img
{
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%; /* CENTER THE DIV */
    top: 50%;/* CENTER THE DIV */
    margin: -16px 0 0 -16px; /* CENTER THE DIV */
}
```